# Cosmos db readDocument api not work in stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

A simple stored procedure using `readDocument` function in CosmosDB/DocumentDB, but it does not work.

```
function testRead() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var docId =  collection.getSelfLink() + 'docs/myDocId';

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.readDocument(docId, {}, function (err, doc, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

it always get error code 400.

> {"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message:
>   {\\"Errors\\":[\\"Encountered exception while executing Javascript.
>   Exception = Error: Error creating request message\\r\\nStack
>   trace: Error: Error creating request message\\n at readDocument
>   (testRead.js:512:17)\\n at testRead (testRead.js:8:5)\\n at
>   __docDbMain (testRead.js:18:5)\\n at Global code (testRead.js:1:2)\\"]}\r\nActivityId:
>   2fb0f7ef-c192-4b56-b8bb-9681c9f8fa6e, Request URI:
>   /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer22/partitions/a4cb4962-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
>   RequestStats: , SDK:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0\"}","activityId":"2fb0f7ef-c192-4b56-b8bb-9681c9f8fa6e","substatus":400}

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this: var docId =  collection.getAltLink() + 'docs/myDocId';
-- self link is not for "name routing".

Comment: your solution works, but your missing a slash symbol, it should be '/docs/myDocId'

Answer (score 1):

According to Michael's suggestion, my sample works now, here is the code

```
function testRead() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    var docId =  collection.getAltLink() + '/docs/myDocId';

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.readDocument(docId, {}, function (err, doc, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code like :

```
function testRead() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var docId =  collection.getAltLink() + 'docs/myDocId';
    console.log(collection.getSelfLink() + 'docs/myDocId');

    var isAccepted = collection.readDocument(docId, {}, function (err, doc, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Or you could use follow sample code to query the document, it also contains all of the fields.

```
function testRead() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var query =  "select * from c where c.id = '1'";
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query,function (err, doc, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var response = getContext().getResponse();
        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: to unblock my work, yes, i already use this solution, but i want to figure out why ReadDocument not work. in official document, 'ReadDocument' is ready for users, see https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Collection.html