# Azure CosmosDb Stored Procedure IfMatch Predicate

Tags: javascript, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, etag

In a DocDb stored procedure, as the first step in a process retrieving data that I'm mutating, I read and then use the data iff it matches the etag like so:

```js
collection.readDocument(reqSelf, function(err, doc) {
    if (doc._etag == requestEtag) {
        // Success - want to update
    } else {
        // CURRENTLY: Discard the read result I just paid lots of RUs to read 
        // IDEALLY: check whether response `options` or similar indicates retrieval
                    was skipped due to doc not being present with that etag anymore 
        ...
        // ... Continue with an alternate strategy
    }
});
```

Is there a way to pass an `options` to the `readDocument` call such that the callback will be informed "It's changed so we didn't get it, as you requested" ?

(My real problem here is that I can't find any documentation other than [the `readDocument` undocumentation in the js-server docs](https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Collection.html))

Comment: Wait a second. I started writing up the answer but then I thought, why would you do that? The document that you get from `readDocument` is always the latest document (ofc based on your consistency level). Even if you pass an access condition and the condition isn't met, you will still get the latest document.

Comment: You are seeing it the wrong way. What you need to do is to pass the etag on the update call itself, not the read. That's where the access condition will actually be checked and fail if the document's etag doesn't meet the criteria

Comment: @NickChapsas the advantage of not actually getting the document if it has changed is that the RU charges (and latency due to the data traveling) are avoided - you always pay 1 RU if the etag matches. I get the point of the etag to make the update conditional. In my case, if the etag has changed, then the document has been superseded and I hence need to do a different (more expensive) search (and it's in this case I want to avoid getting data I won't use).

Comment: The problem is that because `readDocument` is not meant to work with an `accessCondition`, even if you provide one that doesn't match the etag, you will still get the latest version of the document without any errors.

Comment: I too suspect that is the case - however its a bit ironic that I could do the same pre-flight check from the client side with an `If-Match` predicate for 1 RU before I invoke the stored proc

Comment: I actually tested it and it is exactly how I described it. You can find the code used here: https://i.imgur.com/bJF77QK.png

Comment: I'm confused now - have you proved it works or fails? If it works, I need to get some OCR sorted and bestow a bounty on you when I integrate it into https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/7efd15de982ac0dc5f3c549319a89cdcaebc6af5/src/Equinox.Cosmos/Cosmos.fs#L350 and get a big throughput boost... Also, I wasn't able to infer that from any samples I've seen - can you cite a source please?

Comment: By "it works", I mean that it won't throw an error if the provided etag is wrong. It shouldn't and it doesn't.

Comment: OK, but that's inconsistent from my point of view - I can do a client side IfMatch and pay 1 RU to check a 3MB doc is still valid, but server side I can't do the same thing? Obviously this is not the mainstream case (an `If-Match` on a _read_) which is probably why it's not covered, but I don't see a better way to manage it (it being obtaining a document that I know the `id` and partition key / collection link of as a first step in a stored proc) - is there a way to do a point-read by id + partition key inside a stored proc ins some efficient manner?

Comment: @NickChapsas you led me to [an even-better 'workaround' that actually solves the problem better than I was hoping was even possible at first in my context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366027/11635). Thanks so much for taking the time to push on this. Can you put a none-liner version of your "the server doesnt work like that" point in an answer so I can Accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do that by creating a `responseOptions` object and passing it to the call.

```
function sample(selfLink, requestEtag) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var responseOptions = { accessCondition: { type: "IfMatch", condition: requestEtag } };

    var isAccepted = collection.readDocument(selfLink, responseOptions, function(err, doc, options) {
        if(err){
            throw new Error('Error thrown. Check the status code for PreconditionFailed errors');
        }

        var response = getContext().getResponse();
        response.setBody(doc);

    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

However, even if the etag you provide is not the one that the document has, you won't get an error and you will properly get the document itself back. It's just not supposed to work with that using the `readDocument` function in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some pushing from @Nick Chapsas, and [this self-answer from @Redman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52435312/11635) I worked out that in my case I can achieve my goal (either read the current document via the self-link, or the newer one that has replaced it bearing the same `id`) by instead generating an Alt link within the stored procedure like so:

```js
var docId = collection.getAltLink() + "/docs/"+req.id;
var isAccepted = collection.readDocument(docId, {}, function (err, doc, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // Will be null or not depending on whether it exists
    executeUpsert(doc);
});
if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("readDocument not Accepted");
```